# Image rendering wrong only on some browsers on mobile

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have a non-square image on my bootstrap-based website (blog) in a column next to a column of text. It's set up so they are left-right if there is enough room and stack if there isn't. Everything looks great on chrome, firefox, and even IE on desktop. Chrome works fine on mobile, but if I use the facebook browser or the default Samsung 'Internet' browser, the picture because very distorted. I actually had to put a `<br>` after the picture just so it wouldn't cover some of the text below on the messed-up browsers. Pics below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
</div>
<div class="img-lg col-xs-12 col-md-6" style="pull-right">
  <a class="popup" href="/data/dp_main1.png">
    <img src="/data/dp_main1.png"> 
  </a>
</div>
```

The `.img-lg` class is

```
.img-lg {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  max-height:340px;
  max-width:360px;
}
```

I've tried with the height,width values commented out and nothing changes.

Here is how it looks on facebook's in-app browser and samsungs internet, and possibly safari (I don't have it so I haven't checked):

[image: messed-up picture]

Here is how it looks on chrome/firefox/etc:

[image: correct version]

Comment: have you defined your viewport using the <meta> tag? whats the css for the wrapper of the image?

Comment: Are you talking about the popup class? That's for a 3rd party library that enlarges it when clicked, at that function seems to work just fine. What do you mean define a viewport?

Comment: nvm, I have defined a viewport     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: okay just send me the css for the div that the image is inside?

Comment: you mean the col-lg-6 col-xs-12? That's bootstrap css, I haven't made any changes to those classes myself.

Comment: try and override the boostrap css to see if changes anything. keep the use of %'w